# Spring security siteminder

Tags: spring-security, certificate, siteminder

I have recently conducted a code security scan using [Veracode](http://www.veracode.com/) software. One of the vulnerabilities they found was [CWE ID 296](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/296.html) (Improper Following of a Certificate's Chain of Trust) with only an URL provided:

[Some domain]/login.fcc?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-0001a0fa-fce9-116f-9124-e48cac184047&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=$SM$h5DAp2mUtJV%2b9BSWU0E5b3HEpwYmd7icGcuJcCzyJ79JnAUSHTDMYaehDLGNNWHM&TARGET=$SM$%2f

Now, I know what a Chain of Trust is but the parameters in the URL does not immediately appear to be related to that. However, what I noticed is that the attribues here are all used by SiteMinder. Since our application uses Spring Security's module to support SiteMinder, I would like to know if you guys have any idea of what that is.

Have there been any unresolved issues on the project's queue that relate to Chain of Trust being improperly checked? I did a brief scan there but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is it possible that the vulnerability reported was for the web server that is hosting the https URL for login.fcc. This does not seem like a SiteMinder issue.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to figure that out. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to read this URL in a way that helps me understand the issue. As I said, the only thing that's obvious to me is that these GET parameters are all for SiteMinder attributes which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well the parameters mean the following:

TYPE=33554433: This is the type of login

REALMOID=06-0001a0fa-fce9-116f-9124-e48cac184047: This is the OID of the SiteMinder realm for which authentication has been requested.

GUID: Not sure

SMAUTHREASON=0: The reason the user is redirected to login URL. 0 means redirect because no existing session authentication needed.

METHOD=GET: The http method which was used to access the protected resource

SMAGENTNAME=$SM$h5DAp2mUtJV%2b9BSWU0E5b3HEpwYmd7icGcuJcCzyJ79JnAUSHTDMYaehDLGNNWHM: The name of the agent that made the request

TARGET=$SM$%2f: The URL to redirect to post successful authentication.

Thanks Avijit

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will do some research on these values.

Comment: I would suggest that you contact your web server admin guys and ask them to research on the vulnerability as well. In all probability this seems to be a issue with how the server handles the SSL chain.

Comment: I am a bit new to web security so need a little clarificaiton here. So this is for a web-app (that uses Spring Security framework) hosted on a Tomcat application server on cloud. I'd assume you mean either the Tomcat or cloud's not setup properly? If that's the case, that comes as a surprise to me since I was under the impression that it should be the webapp (being the service provider) not properly authenticating.

Comment: I am assuming you are using SSL connections for the URL you quoted above.. Is the SSL certificate self-signed or provided a third party?

Comment: That I'll have to find out. Do you have any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Well.. Open the SSL certificate and check the Issued By field value. It should be a trusted certificate provider. The list of trusted CAs is available on https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have admin access to the testing server to check this. I'd imagine even if it is self-signed the service provider should still reject and that's what I am trying to zero in.

Comment: You should be able to get the certificate from the browser yet.. Refer to this link for IE.. http://www.herongyang.com/PKI/HTTPS-IE-8-View-Server-Certificate-Detail.html